# how to make a specific link not to be affected by its current default style?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok, I got a link with its following style

```
a:link, a:visited {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid green;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

a:hover, a:active {
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
}
```

That is good for all normal links

However, for this specific link I don't want it inherit anything from its current default style. I want it to use other style, so I used id selector

```
#otherLink, #otherLink:visited {  
  color: blue;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#otherLink:hover, #otherLink:active {
  color: red;
}
```

then I set

```
var userName_a = document.createElement('a');

userName_a.setAttribute( 'id', 'otherLink' );
```

The thing is that some styles of `otherLink` got affected to `userName_a` but other current default link styles still affects to `userName_a`.

**So, how to make a specific link not to be affected by its current default style?**

Comment: that's what happens when you declare global style by tag. If you have a lot of other `<a>` for other purposes create a class to do a reset on `a.reset-class` or you end up writing the same property rules over and over

Answer (score 1):

The only way to clear the properties is to re-declare them in your secondary selector to initial, i.e. background-color:initial;

Comment: so we re gonna have some duplicated codes right? can we have a better way?

Comment: That's why they are cascading styles ))

Comment: This is not duplication, but overriding

Comment: This is really the only way, short of creating a class for each and only assigning the correct ones to the corresponding a tags.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see is go back to your base styles and use the NOT pseudo-class to rule out your anchor with the specific ID.

```
a:link:not(#otherLink), a:visited:not(#otherLink) {
    /*styles*/
}
```

It's not ideal but I wanted you to know about the option.

Answer (score 0):

this is yor html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
      a.normal{
        text-decoration: none;
        color:blue;

      }
      a.normal:hover{
        color:green;
      }

      a.special{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: red;
      }

      a.special:hover{
        color:yellow;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="" class="normal">HOME</a>
<a href="" class="normal">ABOUT</a>
<a href="" class="special">DEFAULT</a>


</body>
</html>
```

then when your call to your special link in `js` always use `a.special` and for normal `a.normal`